# git - update all branches to use same version of file

Tags: git

I seem to have 2 different versions of a `site.conf` file in different branches.

Is there a way to tell git that all branches should update the version of the file they are tracking to that used by `master`?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the desired branches.
Once the branch is checked out then you can checkout the file from a specific  commit so you will have the "master" version in your working folder.

```
git checkout <commit_id> <path to file to checkout>
```

If you want to it for all your branches you can write small scrip that does it.